# How many containers are needed for activiti bpm to work ? I see latest edition has 7 containers.

Tags: alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

Activiti BPM latest edition seem to have 7 containers. Are all of them needed ?

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely up to you. We provide spring boot starters that can be used in different ways, so i wonder what are your use case requirements, so we can better recommend a deployment approach.

Notice that Beta1 hasn’t been released yet, so it is a great time to get involved to shape the future of the project.